# How to webscrape data from only specific cells in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape some data from  https://il.water.usgs.gov/gmaps/precip/. I only want specific cells from the row called "RAIN GAGE AT PING TOM PARK AT CHICAGO, IL. Only the cells containing the 1, 3, and 12 hour predictions for rain. What should I fix?

```
    import pandas as pd

    url = "https://il.water.usgs.gov/gmaps/precip/"
    df = pd.read_html(url, flavor="bs4")[0]
    print(df.loc[df[0] == "RAIN GAGE AT PING TOM PARK AT CHICAGO, IL"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is dynamically retrieved from another endpoint returning JSON. You could write a function calling that endpoint and pass in location and desired hours

```
def get_precipitation(location:str, hrs:list):
    import requests
    url = "https://il.water.usgs.gov/gmaps/precip/data/rainfall_outIL_WSr2.json"
    r = requests.get('https://il.water.usgs.gov/gmaps/precip/data/rainfall_outIL_WSr2.json').json()
    data = [i for i in r['value']['items'] if i['title'] == location][0]
    
    for k,v in data.items():
        if k in hrs:
            print(f'{k}={v}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    location = "RAIN GAGE AT PING TOM PARK AT CHICAGO, IL"   
    hrs = ['precip1hrvalue', 'precip3hrvalue', 'precip12hrvalue']

    get_precipitation(location, hrs)
```

Comment: how can one tell if another endpoint such as this exists ?

Comment: use the network tab https://scrapecrow.com/reverse-engineering-intro.html

Comment: excellent: love learning new useful tricks. Thanks,